# Template parameter order matters in gcc but not clang or msvc

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

A friend was compiling some code with clang++; I was failing with g++. In both cases we were using `-std=c++11`.

I distilled it down to the following example:

```
enum A { A_foo = 23 };

class FooBar {

  // This works in both:

  int e1 = first<A_foo, int>();
  int e2 = third<int, (int) A_foo>();

  // Only works in clang:

  //int e3 = second<int, A_foo>();
  //int e4 = third<int, A_foo>();

  template <A val, class U> int first() { return val; }
  template <class U, A val> int second() { return val; }
  template <class U, int val> int third() { return val; }

};

int main() {
  FooBar bar;
}
```

This code compiles in clang++ for all initializations of `eN`. g++, on the other hand, won't compile the commented-out lines, even though `first` and `second` only differ by the order of their template parameters.

Any ideas as to the explanation?

Comment: Can you clarify which line work in which compiler? If `int e = foo2...` works in all compilers why is it commented out, and which ones does `foo4` work in?

Comment: I can confirm that GCC dos not compile the code with the lines uncommented while Clang does. Using uniform initialization makes GCC accept the code but I'm not sure what's the problem.

Comment: Tricky parsing issues with the `<`, no doubt, that somehow made GCC confused about whether the `,` is separating declarators or template arguments. (Compare [CWG 325](http://wg21.link/CWG325).) Note that parenthesizing the *template-id* (i.e., `(second<int, A_foo>)()`) makes GCC compile the code.